# Backbone events hash not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am just trying to get a `Backbone` event has to work.  I have some `html`:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

And I want to assign a click handler when I click the `about` link.  Here is my js:

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var Backbone = require('backbone');
  var headerTemplate = require('hbs!app.templates/header.view');

  var Header = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: headerTemplate,

    render: function() {
      return this.template();
    },

    events: {
      'click #about': 'about'
    },

    about: function() {
      console.log("Clicked About");
    }
  });

  return Header;
});
```

My view gets instantiated in my router.  Here is that code:

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var Backbone = require('backbone');
  var Header = require('views/header.view');
  var MainBody = require('views/main.body.view');

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "main",
    },

    main: function() {
      var header = new Header();
      $('#header').html(header.render());
    }
  });

  return Router;
});
```

When I click on the about link, I get nothing in the console.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please instantiate your view

Comment: Are you sure you are defining your require modules correctly..I am no experience in require..But I think it is like `define('moduleName', function() {})`

Comment: You can define a `require` module either way.  I think this one just looks cleaner.  Also, if it was wrong, the class would not run and it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone delegates events to jQuery by scoping the events to the view `el`, but you are only using your view to render HTML, you never use its container element. See http://jsfiddle.net/398Gr/ for an example

If you want to take advantage of Backbone, handle the insertion of the elements in your view

```
var Header = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: headerTemplate,

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template());
      return this;
    },

    events: {
      'click #about': 'about'
    },

    about: function() {
      console.log("Clicked About");
    }
});
```

and instantiate it with the `el` set:

```
main: function() {
  var header = new Header({el: '#header'});
  header.render();
}
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/398Gr/1/